# Why might my bluetooth controller be sending duplicate packets?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to debug a connection between two devices using a packet sniffer, and one peculiarity I've seen is that the central is sending each request packet 20 or so times on different channels. The peripheral only sends a single response packet. The host is only issuing the requests to the controller once, so I believe the controller is doing something internally to create these duplicates. Another piece of evidence that this is the case is that when I connect to different peripherals, the central is only sending these once.

Is this behavior expected in certain cases or is it a problem?

Here's part of the capture. The rightmost column is the channel number.

```
2474    34.434  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22191µs 0   0   False   419 Sent Pairing Confirm    6
2475    34.457  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22251µs 0   0   False   420 Sent Pairing Confirm    1
2476    34.479  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22250µs 0   0   False   421 Sent Pairing Confirm    14
2477    34.502  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22254µs 0   0   False   422 Sent Pairing Confirm    27
2478    34.524  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22249µs 0   0   False   423 Sent Pairing Confirm    24
2479    34.547  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22251µs 0   0   False   424 Sent Pairing Confirm    7
2480    34.569  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22253µs 0   0   False   425 Sent Pairing Confirm    3
2481    34.592  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22251µs 0   0   False   426 Sent Pairing Confirm    2
2482    34.614  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22253µs 0   0   False   427 Sent Pairing Confirm    1
2483    34.637  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22251µs 0   0   False   428 Sent Pairing Confirm    6
2484    34.659  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22250µs 0   0   False   429 Sent Pairing Confirm    35
2485    34.682  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22253µs 0   0   False   430 Sent Pairing Confirm    28
2486    34.704  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22251µs 0   0   False   431 Sent Pairing Confirm    33
2487    34.727  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22250µs 0   0   False   432 Sent Pairing Confirm    30
2488    34.749  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22253µs 0   0   False   433 Sent Pairing Confirm    5
2489    34.772  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22251µs 0   0   False   434 Sent Pairing Confirm    25
2490    34.794  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22253µs 0   0   False   435 Sent Pairing Confirm    19
2491    34.817  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22251µs 0   0   False   436 Sent Pairing Confirm    4
2492    34.839  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22249µs 0   0   False   437 Sent Pairing Confirm    14
2493    34.862  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22254µs 0   0   False   438 Sent Pairing Confirm    5
2494    34.884  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22250µs 0   0   False   439 Sent Pairing Confirm    22
2497    34.907  Slave_0xdc730e55    LE 1M   SMP 21  151µs   1   0   False   440 Rcvd Pairing Confirm    13
2522    35.424  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22187µs 0   0   False   463 Sent Pairing Random 35
2523    35.447  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22252µs 0   0   False   464 Sent Pairing Random 27
2524    35.469  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22253µs 0   0   False   465 Sent Pairing Random 35
2525    35.492  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22250µs 0   0   False   466 Sent Pairing Random 22
2526    35.514  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22253µs 0   0   False   467 Sent Pairing Random 15
2527    35.559  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  44749µs 0   0   False   469 Sent Pairing Random 26
2528    35.582  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22254µs 0   0   False   470 Sent Pairing Random 18
2529    35.604  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22249µs 0   0   False   471 Sent Pairing Random 30
2530    35.627  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22251µs 0   0   False   472 Sent Pairing Random 1
2531    35.649  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22253µs 0   0   False   473 Sent Pairing Random 25
2532    35.672  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22251µs 0   0   False   474 Sent Pairing Random 18
2533    35.694  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22253µs 0   0   False   475 Sent Pairing Random 9
2534    35.717  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22250µs 0   0   False   476 Sent Pairing Random 27
2535    35.739  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22251µs 0   0   False   477 Sent Pairing Random 16
2536    35.762  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22254µs 0   0   False   478 Sent Pairing Random 18
2537    35.784  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22250µs 0   0   False   479 Sent Pairing Random 28
2538    35.807  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22250µs 0   0   False   480 Sent Pairing Random 33
2539    35.829  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22253µs 0   0   False   481 Sent Pairing Random 20
2540    35.852  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22251µs 0   0   False   482 Sent Pairing Random 22
2541    35.874  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   SMP 21  22253µs 0   0   False   483 Sent Pairing Random 16
2544    35.897  Slave_0xdc730e55    LE 1M   SMP 21  150µs   1   0   False   484 Rcvd Pairing Random 5
2569    36.414  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22191µs 0   0   False   507 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  29
2570    36.437  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22235µs 0   0   False   508 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  0
2571    36.459  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22234µs 0   0   False   509 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  14
2572    36.482  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22238µs 0   0   False   510 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  36
2573    36.504  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22234µs 0   0   False   511 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  3
2574    36.527  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22235µs 0   0   False   512 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  12
2575    36.549  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22237µs 0   0   False   513 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  1
2576    36.572  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22234µs 0   0   False   514 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  4
2577    36.594  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22237µs 0   0   False   515 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  25
2578    36.617  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22235µs 0   0   False   516 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  13
2579    36.639  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22234µs 0   0   False   517 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  21
2580    36.662  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22238µs 0   0   False   518 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  17
2581    36.684  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22233µs 0   0   False   519 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  11
2582    36.707  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22235µs 0   0   False   520 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  7
2583    36.729  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22238µs 0   0   False   521 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  20
2584    36.752  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22234µs 0   0   False   522 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  28
2585    36.774  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22237µs 0   0   False   523 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  7
2586    36.797  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22234µs 0   0   False   524 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  23
2587    36.819  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22235µs 0   0   False   525 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  34
2588    36.842  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22238µs 0   0   False   526 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  33
2589    36.864  Master_0xdc730e55   LE 1M   LE LL   23  22234µs 0   0   False   527 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_REQ  21
2592    36.887  Slave_0xdc730e55    LE 1M   LE LL   13  150µs   1   0   False   528 Control Opcode: LL_ENC_RSP  25
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is this behavior expected in certain cases?

In an ACL connection, the controller will resend the last packet every connection interval until either the receiver acknowledges it, or the supervision timeout expires and the connection is dropped.

Further reading: Bluetooth spec, volume 6, part B, section 4.5.2 and section 4.5.9

> or is it a problem?

There are many reasons why this could happen, such as temporarily poor connection quality, so it is not always a problem. But it can be a strong indication of one. If this happens consistently there is probably something wrong.